# Text viewing in a delimited space

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to visualize a text into a delimited space. If I add a simple TextBlock I have a problem: when the text is longer than the available space, it is cropped at the end. I tried to insert the TextBlock inside a Viewbox: this solution works for a text longer than the available space, but increase the size of the text when it is shorter.
Is there a way to reduce the size of the text only when it is longer than the available space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx), set the [StretchDirection property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.stretchdirection.aspx) to [`DownOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stretchdirection.aspx).

This will set the viewbox to only allow it to scale the content to be smaller, and will prevent it from increasing the size of the content.

```
<Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly">
    <TextBlock>Some text that will only be made smaller.</TextBlock>
</Viewbox>
```

You can also set the [Stretch property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.stretch.aspx) to [`Uniform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch.aspx) to scaling keeps the correct aspect ratio if you have problems with it scaling vertically when you don't want it to.